# Add "Newest" question tab to "root"

Tags: discussion

If I visit this site using "Communities" menu or by by visiting https://meta.stackexchange.com/ then I see this set of buttons:

[image]

There is no "Newest" question tab.

To have "Newest" I have to click burger menu (the leftmost button on top with 3 vertical lines), choose "Questions", then I am at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions and buttons become:

[image]

Only then I am able to *enjoy* the site the way I like (and I like to see newest questions as one can guess, not old ones, not featured, not active, not bugs, not reqs, not hot, not week, not month.. shall I continue?)

I noticed this on Arquade [first](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13139/135338).

I am not sure, but I think it was changed with when new UI comes. Is there an easy way to make me happy? Clicking every time burger menu (3 clicks instead of just one) is quite annoying as you can guess. I would enjoy even more if "Newest" was default *mode*, but someone decided it should be "Active".

Comment: If you have the burger menu it means you're on mobile. You can switch to mobile theme (tap "mobile" in footer) and you'll have the link to /Questions appear without being hidden behind burger menu. One step less.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I call burger menu that leftmost on top button with 3 vertical lines. I am browsing from PC.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the burger menu is also shown on full site if the window size is small enough or the user explicitly disabling left navigation sidebar

Comment: Oh, yeah, I have left navigation sidebar disabled. Hmm.. enabling it would save me 1 click, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you want less clicks, don't disable the shortcuts..

Comment: I've enabled left navigation, now it's 2 clicks, yay! But can it be just one? I can bookmark specific site (directly to that web address with `/questions`), but I like to use "Communities" menu and bookmarking all communities is impractical..

Comment: Actually it's one click. The /questions page remembers your last filter (e.g. "Newest") so once you choose Newest, you'll always get newest when going to /questions. So it's only one click away, on the "Questions" link in the left nav bar. :)

Comment: You are right, I am happy user now. Thanks.

Comment: Also, just found out that such exact request was already made years ago. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's dupe, thanks for finding.